# Use Chart Values from Subchart in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

using 0.13.2 Helm provider terraform, I have a Chart with a subchart nested:

```
├── charts
│   └── postgres
│       ├── Chart.yaml
│       ├── templates
│       │   ├── deployment.yaml
│       │   ├── env.yaml
│       │   └── service.yaml
│       └── values.yaml
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── env.yaml
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   └── service.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

I need to use from the deployment.yml of the postgres subchart, the values of the parent chart. How can I config the configmap of the subchart to get the parent chart values? My current configmap is like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-postgres-env
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  {{- range $key, $val := .Values.environment }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $val | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly do this.  In discussing [Scope, Dependencies, and Values](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#scope-dependencies-and-values), the Helm documentation notes (with a motivating example):

> Charts at a higher level have access to all of the variables defined beneath. So the WordPress chart can access [`.Values.child.setting`]. But lower level charts cannot access things in parent charts, so [the child] will not be able to access [a parent] property. Nor, for that matter, can it access [sibling subchart settings].

You have two options.  If you move the settings under a `global:` key

```yaml
global:
  environment:
    keys: values
```

then the parent and *all* subcharts will be able to access `.Values.global.environment`.  Or, if you move the settings under a key specific to the subchart

```yaml
postgres:
  environment:
    keys: values
```

then the subchart will see `.Values.environment`, and the parent can reference `.Values.postgres.environment`.

(If you can't use a prepackaged PostgreSQL chart, it's not necessarily wrong to flatten these parts into a single chart, making it clear from the filenames that something is `statefulset-postgres.yml` or `svc-postgres.yml`.  Then the templates would be able to use the single `.Values`.)