# Helm pass .Chart.appVersion to dependency

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have 2 helm charts (A, B), where A depends on B.

I want the `.Chart.appVersion` from A to be passed to B during installation, but instead, I get an empty value (the `appVersion` isn't set in B).

How can I pass the value in A to manifests generated from B?

`B/templates/deployment.yaml:`

```
image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
```

Currently, when I install A, the property gets resolved to `image: "repository:"`. But if I set appVersion in A to `1.2.3`, I'd like the property to be `image: "repository:1.2.3"`, which isn't the case currently.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438626/use-chart-values-from-subchart-in-helm